# Webscraping with Scrapy - spyder error processing POST

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i am trying to get data from this website: https://www.illibraio.it/librerie/, the data specifically seems to be stored in multiple https://www.illibraio.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php pages with different lengths.

i followed a tutorial to write this short code, but i dont understand why it doesn't work. i keep getting this error message

```html
ERROR: Spider error processing <POST https://www.illibraio.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php> (referer: https://www.illibraio.it/librerie/)
```

this is my current code for reference, any help is appreciated. im rly beginner level with this thing but i rly need the data from the website...

```html
import scrapy
import json

class Librerie(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Librerie"
    start_urls = ['https://www.illibraio.it/librerie/']
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "Referer": "https://www.illibraio.it/librerie/",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }
    
    data = {
        'nome': 'Mondadori Bookstore - Melegnano',
        'indirizzo': 'Via Zuavi, 8 20077 Melegnano MI',
        'latlong': '{"lat":"45.356655","lng":"9.322607"'
        }
    
    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://www.illibraio.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
        meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,
                                 method='POST',
                                 formdata=self.data,
                                 meta=meta,
                                 callback=self.parse_api, 
                                 headers=self.headers)
    
    def parse_api(self, response):
        raw_data = response.body
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        yield {
            'nome' : data['title'],
            'indirizzo' : data['location'],
            'latlong' : data['coords'],
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an objection to use request module. It may help you

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
import json

cookies = {
'_ga': 'GA1.2.1385472977.1639209109',
'_gid': 'GA1.2.979738495.1639209109',
'_fbp': 'fb.1.1639209110499.1494824473',
'_gat_UA-30151893-1': '1',
}

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0',
'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Origin': 'https://www.illibraio.it',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Referer': 'https://www.illibraio.it/librerie/',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'TE': 'trailers',
}


for req in range(0, 110, 10):
    data = {
    'action': 'get_bookshops',
    'offset': str(req),
    'search': 'prov=&city-lat=&city-lng=&keywords='
    }

    response = requests.post('https://www.illibraio.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
    print(response.status_code)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    for mydata in data["results"]:
        print(mydata['title'])
        print(mydata['location'])
        print(mydata['phone'])
```